# Move entire Library contents with PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Our company is doing a migration from SharePoint sub-sites to new sites.

The only things being moved are document libraries, since we'll be moving a lot of libraries I have looked into doing this with PowerShell.

I have been using PnP PowerShell with `Move-PnPFile`.  But I'm struggling to move an entire library worth of content.  I can only get PowerShell to work for individual folders/files within the library.

I have tried to list items and loop through them to move, but I cannot seem to get this working either.

I'd like to move the library from `https://companyname.sharepoint.com/IT/Test` to `https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/Test`

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://companyname.sharepoint.com/IT' -UseWebLogin

$sourceUrl = 'https://companyname.sharepoint.com/IT/Test/'
$targetUrl = 'https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/Test/'

$allDocs = (Get-PnPListItem -List 'Test').FieldValues

foreach ($item in $allDocs)
{
    Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl ($sourceUrl + $item.FileLeafRef) -TargetUrl ($targetUrl + $item.FileLeafRef) -Force
}
```

Basically this is what I am trying to achieve.  I have tried all sorts of different variations of ways to get items name/path, used relative URLs, different URLs, none has worked for me.  (`Get-PnPListItem` also lists all items, I only need top level files/folders as all sub-files will move with the folder)

I have full admin access permission to both sites, and I am a global administrator.

Answer (score 0):

you can get top level files and folders like this:

```
$allDocs = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $yourList | Where {$_.Name -ne "Forms"}
```

This is how I did it. Property lists is array of my libraries:

```
function MoveFilesAndFoldersToAnotherSiteCollection
{
    foreach($list in $lists)
    {
        $items = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $list | Where {$_.Name -ne "Forms"}
        $targetLibraryUrl = $relativeTargetUrl + '/' + $list;

        foreach($item in $items)
        {
            Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $item.ServerRelativeUrl -TargetUrl $targetLibraryUrl -AllowSchemaMismatch -Force -AllowSmallerVersionLimitOnDestination
            Write-Output "Moved Item: " $item.ServerRelativeUrl
        }
    }
}
```